# USB 3.0 HDD is working in High-Speed mode instead of SuperSpeed

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, flash, usb-3

I've got Asus R500V with one USB 3.0 port. I've installed a proper driver from Acer site.
I've got WD My Passport [USB 3.0 version] and I connected it to the 3.0 port.

Treeview says it's working in High-speed mode instead of superspeed.

The descriptor says It supports SuperSpeed. And after I plug it in - there's a windows notification saying it could work faster, when I connect it to 3.0 port (but it's connected to 3.0 port...)

What should I do to make my WD work in SuperSpeed?

Best regards.

Comment: You may have the right driver from Acer but there may be a hub manufacturer driver update... Lenovo, for example, use a Broadcom wireless chip and the Windows 8 built-in driver doesn't work properly and Broadcom themselves offer a newer driver that works properly. I've just checked the Asus site for USB drivers and it's Intel based but the driver date says March 2012... I wonder if there's a new one...

Comment: This often happens if you're not use USB3.0 cable and it's not plugged all the way in. Exactly what OS are we talking about?

Comment: @Techpumpkin_WD it's Windows 7. It's USB 3.0 cable.

Comment: You can try the method offered in this article to uninstall any old drivers that might be clogging up Windows. http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/usb-drive-or-flash-problems-how-to-cleanup-and-remove-old-usb-storage-drivers.145884/#post-875300

Answer (score 1):

Did you properly inserted the USB cable? Sometimes it is connected sort of "half way" and newer 3.0 pins are not properly linked.

Comment: double checked that, it's connected properly.